# parallism python using multiprocessing

Tags: python, process, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing, process-pool

I have been trying to use multiprocessing module from python to achieve parallism.

I'm able to execute my code, it run in parallel but after some time just only one process finishes its task and the others exit without finishing I know there is join()method that wait all tasks to finish but not work properly. I have been reading multiprocessing's manual page and forums to find out why it isn't working and i haven't figured it out yet.

I think that the problem may be related with some other thing like database or python version my python version 3.10 and i have 8 cores CPU , any help

Here is my code:

I have 5 process (20000 items split to batch of 4000)

```
def process_batch(self, batch_index, batched_payloads):
        payloads = self.import_file.get_payloads_for_import()
        imported_rows = []
        total_payload_count = len(payloads)
        batch_size = frappe.conf.data_import_batch_size or 4000
        for i, payload in enumerate(batched_payloads):
            doc = payload.doc
            row_indexes = [row.row_number for row in payload.rows]
            current_index = (i + 1) + (batch_index * batch_size)
            if set(row_indexes).intersection(set(imported_rows)):
                print("Skipping imported rows", row_indexes)
                if total_payload_count > 5:
                    frappe.publish_realtime(
                        "data_import_progress",
                        {
                            "current": current_index,
                            "total": total_payload_count,
                            "skipping": True,
                            "data_import": self.data_import.name,
                        },
                        user=frappe.session.user,
                    )
                    continue
            try:
                start = timeit.default_timer()
                # insert data to database process_doc method
                doc = self.process_doc(doc)
                processing_time = timeit.default_timer() - start
                eta = self.get_eta(current_index, total_payload_count, processing_time)
                if self.console:
                    update_progress_bar(
                        f"Importing {total_payload_count} records",
                        current_index,
                        total_payload_count,
                    )
                elif total_payload_count > 5:
                    frappe.publish_realtime(
                        "data_import_progress",
                        {
                            "current": current_index,
                            "total": total_payload_count,
                            "docname": doc.name,
                            "data_import": self.data_import.name,
                            "success": True,
                            "row_indexes": row_indexes,
                            "eta": eta,
                        },
                        user=frappe.session.user,
                    )
                    # commit after every successful import
                frappe.db.commit()
            except Exception:
                # rollback if exception
                frappe.db.rollback()
```

here my code for multiprocessing

```
def import_data()
  batch_size = frappe.conf.data_import_batch_size or 4000
    
         workers = []
            for batch_index, batched_payloads in enumerate(frappe.utils.create_batch(payloads, batch_size)):
                        p = Process(target=self.process_batch, args=(batch_index, batched_payloads))
                        p.start()
                        workers.append(p)
           for worker in workers:
                worker.join()
```

same thing if I do :

```
processes_count = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
        pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes_count)
        #pool = multiprocessing.Pool(4)
        for batch_index, batched_payloads in enumerate(
            frappe.utils.create_batch(payloads, batch_size)):
            pool.apply_async(self.process_batch, args=(batch_index, batched_payloads))
        pool.close()
        pool.join()
```

edit:

same thing with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor

```
batches = enumerate(frappe.utils.create_batch(payloads, batch_size))
with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=processes_count) as executor:
            executor.map(self.process_batch, batches)
```

same thing with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor submit()

```
with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=processes_count) as executor:
            future_to_batch = [executor.submit(self.process_batch, batch_index, batched_payloads) for batch_index, batched_payloads in enumerate(frappe.utils.create_batch(payloads, batch_size))]
            for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(future_to_batch):
                future.result()
```

Comment: We need to see what *process_batch* is doing. Also, you should probably use some kind of Process pool because if *create_batch* is returning large numbers of values you could have far too many processes running concurrently. *concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor* could be a good option

Comment: @Pingu I do :                                                                                                           `with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(4) as executor:
for batch_index, batched_payloads in enumerate(frappe.utils.create_batch(payloads, batch_size)):
 executor.map(self.process_batch, args=(batch_index, batched_payloads)) `                                                                            but not work

Comment: You need to review the documentation for the *map()* function

Comment: Where do you release the lock? Do you even need a lock?

Comment: no it's commented but now when I put post i uncomment it by error  i put aquire and release lock but  don't work in parallel the lock is for one process at a time so i don't need a lock

Comment: concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor  work with executor.submit( )  but the tasks run one after another, with only one task running at a time, so it take more time  , I need to run all process in the same time,

Comment: Use *map()* in accordance with its documentation

Comment: ok i will try again with map

Comment: it work with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor exucutor.map() but same thing like others multiprocessing  solution it run in parallel but after some time just only one process finishes its task and the others exit without finishing